No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' - CORS error
I built a tiny api to help me send emails from my front end to my gmail inbox.
I have installed cors, express and dotenv as dependencies to build this api.
const express = require("express");
const emailjs = require("@emailjs/browser");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env`,
});
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
const PORT = process.env.PORT;
app.post("/api/send_email", async (request, response) => {
  console.log(request.body);
  const { senderEmail, senderName, emailSubject, message } = request.body;

  const service_id = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID;
  const template_id = process.env.REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_ID;
  const user_id = process.env.REACT_APP_USER_ID;
  const public_key = process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_KEY;
  const templateParams = {
    to_name: "Cora",
    from_name: senderName,
    from_email: senderEmail,
    message: message,
    subject: emailSubject,
  };
  try {
    response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    emailjs
      .send(service_id, template_id, templateParams, public_key)
      .then(() => {
        response.status(201).send({ msg: "Message sent!" });
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    response.status(500).send({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
});
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is online, listening on port ${PORT}...`);
});


I went online after the following error showed up in my console:
/contact:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://contact-functionlity.onrender.com/api/send_email' from origin 'https://alfredo-galvez.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

and in most videos I saw on youtube mentioned installing cors and use it in your app, which is what I have done.
I also tried setting up the response headers using:
app.use(cors({

    origin: 'https://alfredo-galvez.netlify.app'
}))


I am a little bit stuck and have been trying to understand what is going on for a quite a while now, wondering is someone could help me out.

The error is pretty clear: the server on https://contact-functionlity.onrender.com does not allow pages that live on the origin https://alfredo-galvez.netlify.app from accessing its data. So your website (not your server, but one of the JS on the page your server's serving up) is trying to fetch data from a URL that the remote server says your page code is not allowed to interact with. Which usually means you're either not calling the right URL, you forget to include tokens that pass a cors check, or you're literally trying to use a service you simply don't have production access to.
